# How can I replace string in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For example:

```
for /F "taken=1,2* delims=;" %%i in(%TABLES%) do(
echo select %%j from %%i; | sed -e “s/,/||’,’||/g” -e “s/@/||’@’/g” >> %TABLES_OUT/¥%%i.sql
```

I want to replace string string instead of `sed`.
Like this

```
, ➡︎ ||’,’||
@ ➡︎ ||’@
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The reference given by @Mofi is a good one. A significant part of it would be finding that VERTICAL LINE characters must be escaped with `^`.

```
C:>TYPE replstr.bat
@ECHO OFF
SET "S=now,is,the@time,for@all"
ECHO %S%
SET "S2=%S:,=^|^|,^|^|%"
ECHO %S2%
SET "S3=%S2:@=^|^|@^|^|%"
ECHO %S3%

C:>CALL replstr.bat
now,is,the@time,for@all
now||,||is||,||the@time||,||for@all
now||,||is||,||the||@||time||,||for||@||all
```